# SetTimeOut dinâmico com PHP

Tags: jquery, settimeout

Estou tentando que uma hora de um determinado `post` atualize a cada **1** minuto.

Código:

```
setTimeout(function() {     
   var ID = $(this).attr('id').split('hora')[1]; // pega o ID e retira a parte "like"
   $.get('index.php?hora=1&id='+ID, function(resultado){
   $('#hora'+ID).html(resultado);
});    
}, 2000 );
```

***Erro***

> `index.php`:502 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `split` of undefined(…)

Comment: como está vindo o attr id?

Comment: <div class="hora" id="hora<?php echo $row['idd']; ?>">
<?php 
          
          $dataantiga = $row['datap']; 

echo tempo_decorrido(date($dataantiga));

          ?></div>

Comment: Se mudar `$(this)` para `$('.hora')`, funciona? Suspeito que esse `$(this)` não esteja referenciando o objeto correto.

Comment: Agora não deu erro, masss não funcionou :\

Comment: Me ajuda @RicardoMoraleida

Comment: "não funcionou" não é uma boa descrição de erro @ViniciusHenzel, lembre-se que a gente só sabe sobre o seu problema o que você escreveu na pergunta. Se incluir mais informações fica mais fácil ajudar. Se incluir um exemplo do attr ID como ele aparece no navegador (ou seja, depois de processado o PHP) ajuda também.

Comment: desculpa a forma que eu falei Ricardo, bom agora eu percebi postando duas mensagens, que uma atualizou, a outra não... estranho... vou te mostrar como está, depois de processado: <div class="hora" id="hora196">
3 minuto atrás</div>

Comment: Gente que estranho, eu percebi que no "código de fonte" ta atualizado o horário, mas visilmente não, ta parado... Estranho!!!

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida pelo codigo de fonte atualiza, e visivel não

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `this` dentro do setTimeout não é o que pensas. O setTimeout corre em contexto de execução `window`, por isso o `this` não é o elemento que pretendes.

Tens de te referir ao elemento que queres e depois ir buscar o ID. Algo assim:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#oMeuElemento');
setTimeout(function() {
    var id = el.id.split('hora')[1]; // pega o ID e retira a parte "like"
    $.get('index.php?hora=1&id=' + id, function(resultado) {
        $('#hora' + id).html(resultado);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Se queres que atualize em cada 1 minuto, tens de mudar o `2000` (que é 2 segundos) e colocar `60000` (ou seja 60 segundos x 1000 milisegundos)

Comment: Oi amigo, eu tentei mas ele só atualiza no código de fonte, visivelmente não, por que será ?

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel o `$.get` é executado? O que dá `console.log(id, resultado);` dentro desse `$.get`?

Comment: Sim, tanto que atualiza pelo código de fonte, só visilmente que não.

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel podes responder o que dá o `console.log` que pedi em cima?

Comment: Como eu vejo isso? Pelo CTRL + SHIFT + N não aparece erro nenhum

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null(…)

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel ok. E o que colocaste como ID aqui -> `var el = document.querySelector('#oMeuElemento');`?

Comment: var el = document.querySelector('.hora');

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel esse elemento não é encontrado, por isso o erro. Ele está lá? ou é adicionado mais tarde?

Comment: <div class="hora" id="hora<?php echo $row['idd']; ?>">
<?php 
          
          $dataantiga = $row['datap']; 

echo tempo_decorrido(date($dataantiga));

          ?></div>

Comment: To tão triste, poxa, não da de jeito nenhum

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel `var el = document.querySelector('.hora');` dá `null`. quando esse código é corrido o HTML ainda não está lá.

Comment: Eu botei depois da div e não deu mais o erro, mas só atualiza no código de fonte, aff

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel é dificil adivinhar como o teu código está. Cria um jsFiddle com o problema e coloca aqui. 2 minutos depois está resolvido.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/th8hwhdr/

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel o que é suposto trazer o `resultado`?

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel ^ https://jsfiddle.net/5ppyr6s8/

Comment: DEU CERTO MUITO OBRIGADO var el = document.querySelector('.hora');
var tempo = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    var id = el.id.split('div')[1]; // pega o ID e retira a parte "like"
    $.get('index.php?hora=1&id=' +id, function(resultado) {
        el.innerHTML = resultado + ''
    });
}, 500);